# @IBDesignable error: Failed to update auto layout status

Tags: ios, admob

My project shows me the below error in the storyboard. My project is build successfully and also run successfully in the simulator, but still the error exists when I open the storyboard.

Error:

> Failed to render and update auto layout status for previewController (80C-7j-jFY): dlopen(GoogleMobileAds.framework, 1): no suitable image found.

> Did find:
> GoogleMobileAds.framework: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

How can I avoid it?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 8 - IB Designables - Failed to render and update auto layout status, The agent crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732312/xcode-8-ib-designables-failed-to-render-and-update-auto-layout-status-the-a)

Comment: We had try all given solutions, but it didn't work in my project in xcode 9.3.

Answer (score 8):

For Xcode version 9 and later, you have to downgrade your pod repository to remove this problem.

For this what you have to do:

#### Step 1

Steps which you have to follow:

```
sudo gem list cocoapods

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.4.0
```

#### Step 3

Go to your project Directory and *update your pod* like

```
pod update
```

#### Step 3

Clear your project as well as derived data. Build and run your project. This error will be removed after this.

Add this script on your POD file:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
end
```

***Note***: if you are facing this issues on Xcode 10 and later, follow all the steps with `sudo gem install cocoapods` instead of `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.4.0`. It works for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me and I can't downgrade to 1.4.0, because one of pods I use, requires 1.5.0...

Answer (score 0):

Try `pod install`. It temporarily solves this problem.