# Xcode 10.1 - "IB Designables. Failed to render and update auto layout status". The agent crashed

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an issue where my storyboard failed to render the layout, so I can't add constraints and also can't see the layout of my viewController.

[image: Issues Image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: This sort of thing is usually fixed by restarting Xcode and/or your Mac. This will restart the agent and allow it to start rendering your UI again. Have you tried this already?

Comment: @siburb Yes I was tried many times restrat and deleting derive data folder

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66101455/edit).

Comment: IB = [Interface Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder)

Answer (score 2):

All the previous answers did not help, but I figured it out.

In the *@IBInspectable didSet* property I was calling the common setup() function to utilize my view. However, I was trying to adjust a textField without checking whether it was nil or not. That's why I was getting "failed to render" problem and also a run time crash.

For example:

```
@IBInspectable var isTitleEnabled: Bool = true{
    didSet{ setup() }
}
```

And the setup() function was:

```
private func setup(){
    textField.isSecureTextEntry = isPassword
}
```

which is wrong. Xcode doesn't allow the subviews to be modified in this way.

When the [Interface Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) (IB) component is rendered, Xcode thinks that it is not initialized yet, so it raises an error. To solve this misunderstanding, we need to make sure that the Interface Builder component is **not** nil.

So, instead we need to use it like that:

```
guard textField != nil else { return }
textField.isSecureTextEntry = isPassword ? true : false
```

The Interface Builder component don't need only to be a UITextField. It is valid for other Interface Builder components like UILabel, UIImageView, etc.

Comment: You can simplify your solution code to just `textfield?.isSecureTextEntry = isPassword ? true : false`.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer *[@IBDesignable error: Failed to update auto layout status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644306/ibdesignable-error-failed-to-update-auto-layout-status/52790289#52790289)*.

Or just try go to *Editor* → *Refesh All Views* in your *Storyboard* selection.