# Xcode: Failed to render and update auto layout status for UIView: the agent crashed

Tags: cocoapods, xcode10.2, swift5

I'm using Xcode 10.2.1 and swift 5.1 in my new project, and it's going to be a big project in future.(cocoapods version is 1.7.3)

in all xib files (for example ConfirmTransactionDetailsView.xib that contains some UILabel and UISwitch) after changing some values like background color or text alignment, these changes does not show in Interface builder.
or some times after selecting another xib files Xcode show me a blank window(UIView)

[image]

and after that I'm getting this error in Xcode(furthermore I can build and run app):

[image]

I tried these solutions but none of them works for me:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50520336/8425034
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52790289/8425034

how can I solve this problem? I mean after changing back ground color or text alignment see that changes in xib file quickly(don't need to quit Xcode and delete DerivedDate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the default value for your @IBInspectable so it won't fail