# method does not override any method from its superclass Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm having the error "method does not override any method from its superclass" in XCode 8 when I tried to set Gradient in custom view file.
The code is

```
override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}
```

when I remove the override, this error occur
"Method 'layerClass()' with Objective-C selector 'layerClass' conflicts with getter for 'layerClass' from superclass 'UIView' with the same Objective-C selector"

Full Code is here :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class CustomView: UIView {

override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}

var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
    return layer as! CAGradientLayer
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.borderWidth = 10.0
    layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 64/225.0, blue: 128/225.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    layer.cornerRadius = 20.0

    let startColor = UIColor(red: 102/225.0, green: 204/225.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let endColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 128/225.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    gradientLayer.colors = [startColor,endColor]
}
}
```

I'm new to iOS plz help me

Comment: `override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layerClass` is now a getter so you have to override the getter:

```
override public class var layerClass: Swift.AnyClass {
    get {
         return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir. but the another error pop up that "Failed to render and update auto layout status for ViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): the agent crashed"

Comment: Can you tell the methods you have implemented in your class?

Comment: Refer @Azure's Answer answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37257488/3840908 & check that in your project.

Comment: thank you sir. I quit the xcode and reopen the project and the code work thank you.