# Xcode Storyboard Fail to show (render) ViewControllers (The agent crashed)

Tags: swift, xcode, uistoryboard, ibinspectable

I'm running Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001) on MacBook Pro 2016

- **Processor:** 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7
- **Memory:** 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- **Graphic:** Radeon Pro 450 2 GB and Intel HD Graphics 530 1536 MB
- **Storage:** 256GB SSD
- **Free Storage:** 45GB SSD

  When i try to open storyboards i see a `Storyboard` with transparent `ViewControllers` but those `ViewControllers` already have `UIViews` and backgrounds but Xcode doesn't show,This remains for more than 20 minutes, then `UIViews` appear

This is how my @IBInspectable class looks like:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class BorderButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

}
```

Im getting error The agent crashed:

[image]

See picture below:

[image]

### What i've done:

- Cleaning build folder
- Removing Derived Data
- Close Xcode and re open
- Free up ram
- [Solutions from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265906/ibdesignable-crashing-agent)

but none of above worked for me.

Comment: Are you using IBInspectable ?

Comment: @MayankPatel yes i provided code

Comment: that is the issue i already facing this type of issue if you remove that class of who has IBInspectable this element then storyboard looks like screenshot has!

Comment: Try following these steps one by one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732312/xcode-8-ib-designables-failed-to-render-and-update-auto-layout-status-the-a

Comment: @frndev it will not work tried all steps this issue is of IBInspectable

Comment: solutions was around Delete Derive Data folder. i already done this @frndev

Comment: yes it will not help but when you do back and forth of storyboard then this issue will came again

Comment: I see, It's weird bug.. Sometimes I had to remove the IBInspectable, clean, build, see that it is removed and then add IBInspectable again. Hope you find the solution and share it ;)

Comment: i am facing this issue from many times but didn't found any solution for this so mostly i am avoiding the use of IBInspectable that is the temp solution so far !

Comment: @frndev also i removed IBInspectable and add after closing xcode and removing derived data but nothing changed, i believe that it occurred everytime storyboard going to render more than 1 view controller