# IOS. Remove IBDesignable constrain

Tags: ios, constraints, ibdesignable

I am using third party lock screen [JKLlockscreen](https://github.com/tiny2n/JKLLockScreenViewController) in my project. and the lockscreen uses IBDesignable constrain. but  it is not completely fitted in iphone 4 screen or etc. when i set , moreover it gives error like this in storyboard.

> file:///Users/usersname/Desktop/untitled%20folder/projectname/LockScreenViewController/JKLLockScreenViewController.xib: error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of JKLLockScreenNumber: dlopen(projectname.app, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       projectname.app: mach-o, but wrong architecture

i have found solution for this error in this [Failed to render IBDesignable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799054/failed-to-render-instance-of-ib-designables) stackoverflow question. but i am not able to solve this problem.

so, i want to remove this IBDesignables Constrain and want to set my own constrain. how can i clear this constrain ?